# media query of (min-width: 1800px) isn't working at 1800px?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Hey friends for some odd reason the media query of min-width(1800px) isn't working? I'm using my friends 1900px monitor and when I shrink down to 1800px the media query of (1700px) is catching instead? this media query is placed above the 1800px query, so the order is right. I'm confused any help would be awesome. Thanks:)

https://jsfiddle.net/sre3vb7y/

p.s the html posted below is just there so I can post this fiddle link.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Contact | Kane Concrete & Construction LLC</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="contact.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo|Bitter|Lato|Montserrat|Noto+Sans|Open+Sans|Poppins|Roboto|Sarabun|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Asap|Krub|Oxygen|Rajdhani|Staatliches|Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="contact-wrapper">
   <nav>
    <div class="logo">
     <i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
     <div class="ham-menu">
      <div class="m1" id="m1"></div>
      <div class="m2" id="m2"></div>
      <div class="m3" id="m3"></div>
     </div>
     <ul>
      <li class="after"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="about.html#services">Services</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>

   <h1>Contact Us</h1>
  </div> 
 </header>

 <section class="contact" id="quote">
  <h2>Get in touch</h2>

  <div class="container">
   <div class="quote-info">
    <p>Get a Quote</p>

    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email">

    <textarea name="project-details" id="" cols="40" rows="7" placeholder="Give us the specifics on your project"></textarea>

    <button class="send-quote">Send</button>
   </div>

   <div class="contact-info">
    <h3>Contact info</h3>

    <div class="contact-numbers">
     <div>
      <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
      <p>(208)546-7827 -Matt</p>
      <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
      <p>(208)546-7827 -Keegan</p>
     </div>

     <div>
      <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
      <p>P.O. Box 50860 IF, ID 83405</p>
      <i class="fas fa-at"></i>
      <p>KaneConcrete@fake.com</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>

 <hr>
 
 <section class="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="links">
    <div class="inner">
     <h1><span>Quick Links</span></h1>

     <a href="index.html">Home</a>
     <a href="about.html">About</a>
     <a href="about.html#services">Services</a>
     <a href="careers.html">Careers</a>
     <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
     <a href="contact.html#quote">Quote</a>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="social">
    <div class="inner">
     <h1><span>Social</span></h1>

     <i class="fab fa-linkedin"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>
     <i class="fab fa-facebook"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>
     <i class="fab fa-twitter-square"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>

     <button name="msg">Send</button>
     <textarea name="msg" class="footer-textarea" cols="45" rows="5" placeholder="Send is some feedback..."></textarea>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="contact">
    <div class="inner" class="wrap">
     <h1><span>Contact</span></h1>

     <p>(208)546-7827 - <span class="dark">Matt</span></p>
     <p>(208)546-7827 - <span class="dark">Keegan</span></p>
     <p><span class="dark">Address</span> - P.O. Box 50860 IF, ID 83405</p>
     <p><span class="dark">Email</span> - KaneConcrete@fake.com</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="copyright"><span>&copy; 2019 - Kane Concrete & Construction | ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</span></div>
 </section>
 <script src="../script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using `@media screen and (min-width: 1800px) {}` its means above or equals to  `1800px` not less then `1800px` thats why media query is not working on shrink down to 1800px instead you use `max-width:1800px`

Comment: it wasn't less than 1800?

Comment: use `max-width:1800px` in `@media screen and (max-width:1800px) {}` if you want media query is working on shrink down to 1800px